# Notepad++ Regex for remove text in line after first two words

Tags: regex, notepad++

so I have a list that goes like this:

```
AudioQuest FLX-14/2
Abbey Road Cable Monitor Speaker Cable
```

and in in the first line I need to remove everything after first word and in the second one I need to remove everything in line after first TWO words. I figured out how to remove everything after first word, it's

```
.*?$
```

but I'm helpless with the second case. Help me out so I can toggle shortcuts on macros for both  actions and process the list in the way semi-automatical way (Select and apply macros).

Comment: How do you know that you need to remove 1 word in the first line and 2 words in the second line? Is this 2 columns of data?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it seems the data is aligned. And from the example, only the first 10 characters are needed, the rest should be removed.

Find what: `(.{10}).*`

Replace with: `$1`

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in two passes..

> Find:
>
> 1. "***(^[a-z]* [a-z]* )**"
> 2. "***(^[a-z]* )**"
>
> Replace: "\1"